# Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied when trying to write using rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

we are builder a staging server, and to do it we clone our production server. So I create a new bucket for staging and I copy all the content of the production bucket into the staging bucket using the interface provided in Amazon S3 (copy/paste).

The staging application can read and delete file from the staging bucket without problems, but I can't write new file...

Is somebody have an idea? I paste here the policy I have configured:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutAnalyticsConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:CreateBucket",
            "s3:ReplicateObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
            "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:PutBucketAcl",
            "s3:PutObjectTagging",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetIpConfiguration",
            "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
            "s3:GetBucketWebsite",
            "s3:PutReplicationConfiguration",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:GetBucketNotification",
            "s3:PutBucketCORS",
            "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetReplicationConfiguration",
            "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutBucketNotification",
            "s3:PutBucketLogging",
            "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
            "s3:GetAnalyticsConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
            "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration",
            "s3:ListBucketByTags",
            "s3:GetInventoryConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketTagging",
            "s3:PutAccelerateConfiguration",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetBucketLogging",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "s3:ReplicateTags",
            "s3:RestoreObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetObjectVersionTorrent",
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:PutBucketTagging",
            "s3:GetBucketRequestPayment",
            "s3:GetObjectTagging",
            "s3:GetMetricsConfiguration",
            "s3:DeleteBucket",
            "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:PutMetricsConfiguration",
            "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
            "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
            "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "s3:PutInventoryConfiguration",
            "s3:PutIpConfiguration",
            "s3:GetObjectTorrent",
            "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",
            "s3:PutBucketWebsite",
            "s3:PutBucketRequestPayment",
            "s3:GetBucketCORS",
            "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ReplicateDelete",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::naturebooker-staging",
            "arn:aws:s3:::naturebooker_staging/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:HeadBucket",
            "s3:ListObjects"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Have to checked permissions on the new bucket? I believe they are, by default, private (or whatever they call it) and that you need to switch that to be able to access it.

Comment: Have you enabled CORS in the new bucket?

Comment: @GaryVernonGrubb no CORS are not enabled on both bucket.

Comment: @RockwellRice bucket is not private as I can read it and destroy element from it via my application.

Comment: Yes sorry. I confused or with a web app.

Comment: @denis Morin please check if the resource name is correct. I see _ instead of -

Comment: @GaryVernonGrubb thanks man you got it _ instead of -. made the change and everything goes well.

Comment: @denis Morin. Happy to help. I've added it as an answer, please mark as accepted when you have a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if the resource name is correct. I see _ instead of -

Answer (score 0):

solved resource name was bad, should be - instead of _